# postLink() in cakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink

I just created the CRUD operations in cakephp 3.x. I am deleting the records using postLink() function.

```
$this->Form->postLink("<i class='fa fa-remove'></i>", ['action' => 'delete', $role->id], ['escape' => false],['title' => 'Delete', 'class' => 'users'])]);
```

It doesn't set the class for my delete icon. I need set the class name for this delete icon. So that I can create my own dialog box. If I  removed the escape attribute means its create my class but it doesn't display my icon. Also I changed the order of escape and class even that also not working.  Please someone help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use a proper IDE? Did you check the amount of attributes you *may* use for postLink()?
The documentation clearly states: postLink($title, $url, $options).
Why are you using a forth then? Of course that one will be ignored.

So it should be this instead:

```
$this->Form->postLink(
    "<i class='fa fa-remove'></i>", // first
    ['action' => 'delete', $role->id],  // second
    ['escape' => false, 'title' => 'Delete', 'class' => 'users'] // third
);
```

Comment: It helps to use a proper IDE and/or debug it properly before asking the questions.

Comment: From next time sure i will start using that.